# grep files based on name prefixes

Tags: bash, grep

I have a question on how to approach a problem I've been trying to tackle at multiple points over the past month. The scenario is like so:

I have a a base directory with multiple sub-directories all following the same sub-directory format:

`A/{B1,B2,B3}` where all `B*` have a `pipeline/results/` directory structure under them.

All of these `results` directories have multiple `*.xyz` files in them. These `*.xyz` files have a certain hierarchy based on their naming prefixes. The naming prefixes in turn depend on how far they've been processed. They could be, for example, `select.xyz`, `select.copy.xyz`, and `select.copy.paste.xyz`, where the operations are `select`, `copy` and `paste`. What I wish to do is write a `ls | grep` or a `find` that picks these files based on their processing levels.

EDIT:

The processing pipeline goes `select` -> `copy` -> `paste`. The "most processed" file would be the one with the most of those stages as prefixes in its filename. i.e. `select.copy.paste.xyz` is more processed than `select.copy`, which in turn is more processed than `select.xyz`

For example, let's say

`B1/pipeline/results/` has `select.xyz` and `select.copy.xyz`,

`B2/pipeline/results/` has `select.xyz`

`B3/pipeline/results/` has `select.xyz`, `select.copy.xyz`, and `select.copy.paste.xyz`

How can I write a `ls | grep`/`find` that picks the most processed file from each subdirectory? This should give me `B1/pipeline/results/select.copy.xyz`, `B2/pipeline/results/select.xyz` and `B3/pipeline/results/select.copy.paste.xyz`.

Any pointer on how I can think about an approach would help. Thank you!

Comment: What is meant by "most processed"?

Comment: "Most processed" is explained by the example. But what about the directory structure? Is `.xyz` only a placeholder? Can there be different extension in the same directory, for instance the two files `select.txt` and `select.html`? And what about the A in `A/{B1,B2,B3}`? Is the A a placeholder too?

Comment: @codeforester I apologize - I'll add that detail to make it explicit. The processing pipeline goes `select` > `copy` > `paste`. The"most processed" file would be the one with the most of those stages as prefixes in its filename.

Comment: @Socowi That's a good question. I did not want to add unnecessary complications - I should have left out the subdirectory part entirely. The `pipeline/results` subdirectory tree is consistent throughout. And for the current scenario's sake, the `.xyz` extension is constant. We could of course explore how to process variable filenames, but that'd need to follow _some_ naming conventions too.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, we will ignore the upper part `A/B{1,2,3}` of the directory structure. All files in some `.../pipeline/results/` directory will be considered, even if the directory is `A/B1/doNotIncludeMe/forbidden/pipeline/results`. We assume that the file extension `xyz` is constant.

A simple solution would be to loop over the directories and check whether the files exist from back to front. That is, check if `select.copy.paste.xyz` exists first. In case the file does not exist, check if `select.copy.xyz` exists and so on. A script for this could look like the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
# print paths of the most processed files

shopt -s globstar nullglob
for d in **/pipeline/result; do
    if [ -f "$d/select.copy.paste.xyz" ]; then
        echo "$d/select.copy.paste.xyz"
    elif [ -f "$d/select.copy.xyz" ]; then
        echo "$d/select.copy.xyz"
    elif [ -f "$d/select.xyz" ]; then
        echo "$d/select.xyz"
    else
        # there is no file at all
    fi
done
```

It does the job, but is not very nice. We can do better!

```
#! /bin/bash
# print paths of the most processed files

shopt -s globstar nullglob
for dir in **/pipeline/result; do
    for file in "$dir"/select{.copy{.paste,},}.xyz; do
        [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file" && break
    done
done
```

The second script does exactly the same thing as the first one, but is easier to maintain, adapt, and so on. Both scripts work with file and directory names that contain spaces or even newlines.

In case you don't have whitespace in your paths, the following (hacky, but loop-free) script can also be used.

```
#! /bin/bash
# print paths of the most processed files

shopt -s globstar nullglob
files=(**/pipeline/result/select{.copy{.paste,},}.xyz)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | sed -r 's#(.*/)#\1 #' | sort -usk1,1 | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: Thank you - this is awesome. It's a couple of extra steps, but definitely worth it. I googled and learnt the parameter expansion in glob with the `{`s. Could you maybe explain the `#`s in the `sed` please? I've never used `#`s in `sed` and I've done a LOT of `sed`. EDIT: NVM I googled and it apparently serves the same function as a backslash - just a delimiter :)

Comment: Does the `sort -u` work only because `.copy` and `.paste` are alphabetically before `.xyz`? What if the extension were still constant, but a `.fyz`?

Comment: `sort -u` should work even for `.aaa`. The `sed` before `sort` separates the list of files into two columns: 1. path without file name, 2. file name. We only sort by the first column, that is we group by sub-directories. The order of files in each group stays the same* (we wrote `{select{.copy`... such that the most processed file always comes first). `sort` then picks the first line of every group. ---------------------- * Actually, there was a hidden bug: `sort` may change the order of equal lines. We have to use `sort -s` to ensure stability.

Comment: `sed 's/.../.../'` can also be written as `sed 'sC...C...C'` where `C` is a character of your choice. I used `#` instead of `/` so that we don't have to escape the `/` inside the regex. You could actually write `sed -r 's/(.*\/)/\1 /'`, but the *leaning stick syndrom* can be very hard to read: \/\\\/\/\\\/\/\\ :)

Comment: the delimiter choice makes a lot of sense now - thank you. Also, I had no idea sort could perform group + uniquify by just a part of the input. That is invaluable information. And now thanks to you, I've also explored stability in sorting. This has been a wonderful learning exercise - thank you so much!